# Find Value of $\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec b \cdot \vec c+\vec a \cdot \vec c$?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

> > Let $\vec a, \vec b,\vec c$ be three unit vector such that $\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec b \cdot \vec c-\vec a \cdot \vec c=\frac{3}{2}$ then value of $\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec b \cdot \vec c+\vec a \cdot \vec c$

**My Approach:**
let $\vec a \cdot \vec b=\vec b \cdot \vec c=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\vec a \cdot \vec c =\frac{-1}{2}$

So,

$\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec b \cdot \vec c+\vec a \cdot \vec c=\frac{1}{2}$

**I got the answer but how do i prove that $\vec a \cdot \vec b=\vec b \cdot \vec c=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\vec a \cdot \vec c =\frac{-1}{2}$**

**or**

**Is this question wrong?**

Comment: hint: $|\vec{a} - \vec{b} + \vec{c}|^2 = ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without complex numbers. From the comment of achille hui it follows that $b=a+c$ since $|a-b+c|^2=0$.

Now this implies from the condition and the fact the all vectors are unit vectors:

$|a+c|^2-a \cdot c=3/2$

Therefore expanding we get $a \cdot c=-1/2$

The wanted expression is instead:

$|a+c|^2+a\cdot c=1+1+3a \cdot c=1/2$

That is equal to the result of Jack D'Aurizio.

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint of achille hui,

$$ |\vec{a}-\vec{b}+\vec{c}|^2 = 3-2(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}-\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}) = 0$$
hence $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are unit vector such that $\vec{a}+\vec{c}=\vec{b}$. By suitably rotating these vectors by the same angle (the dot products are not affected) we may assume without loss of generality that $\vec{b}=(-1,0)$, or $\vec{b}=-1$ by embedding $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $\vec{a}+\vec{c}$ is real the vectors $\vec{a},\vec{c}$ have to be conjugated, then it is simple to check that $\{\vec{a},\vec{c}\}=\{\omega,\omega^2\}$ where $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$ is a primitive third root of unity. $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ (the centroid of an equilateral triangle is also the circumcenter), so $-1+\omega+\omega^2=-2$ and $|\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}|^2$ equals $4$. On the other hand
$$ |\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}|^2 = 3+2\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}+\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a}\right)$$
hence the last term between brackets has to be equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could you please clarify how centroid and circumcenters enter the proof?

Comment: @Thomas: $1,\omega,\omega^2$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle in the complex plane. The centroid is $(1+\omega+\omega^2)/3$ and the circumcenter is at the origin (since $1,\omega,\omega^2$ are unit vectors). Since for a regular polygon the centroid and the circumcenter are the same point, $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$. By the way, this just follows from $\omega^3-1=0$ and $\omega-1\neq 0$.

Comment: Perfect thanks for making this explicit !